# Xcode: How to list all the methods for a variable?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, search-suggestion

On Intelli j you simply write

```
Integer num=1;
num.
```

with a dot after the variable, then it shows a list of all method for the object num.

How to get the same feature on xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has autocomplete for both Swift and Objective-C. In your example with an `Int`, only Swift will have autocompletion, because `Int` is a class in Swift, but a C primitive type in Objective-C. So try autocompletion with a variable you know to be an object, not a primitive.

If it still doesn't work for you, you may want to remove your Derived Data folder, do a clean build, and restart Xcode.

Comment: I'm using objective c and nothing appears

Comment: The integer is just an example because there aren't common classes between languages, just think about NSNumber or any other class object of the framework.